# Windows Service uninstall

Tags: c#, service, windows-services, installation

I tried to uninstall a running windows service written in .net (c#), somehow the service's still existing in services.msc, when I'm trying to install another service with the service name it says an existing service already installed. I forgot to add uninstall in custom action (using project installer .net).

I tried to delete the service using SC DELETE (service name) in cmd with admin rights. Also, delete the service in regedit.exe and in control panel. I also delete the program folder.

Comment: Are you using WiX to package this or some other MSI tool? Neither?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your project directory debug folder under bin from the command prompt then type

```
"c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\installutil -u servicename.exe"
```

I solved the problem in this way.